# SyntaxError in if-statement in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

```
for ch in line:
    ch_good = u"%s" %ch
    if ord(ch_good) == 8212:
        ch_good = '-'
    elif ord(ch_good) == 8220 or ord(ch_good) == 8221:
        ch_good = '"'
    elif ord(ch_good) == 8230:
        ch_good = "..."
    elif ord(ch_good) == 8217:
        ch_good = "'"

    elif ord(ch_good) == 191 or ord(ch_good) == 187 or ord(ch_good) == 239:
        сh_good = ""
```

I have right this error on line 24

```
    сh_good = ""
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Just a thought: check your indentation (tabs vs spaces).

Comment: indentation is correct
I checked it just now.

Comment: @Gandalv: not in this case; it is a *cyrillic es* instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `с` is not an ASCII `c`:

```
>>> '''\
...         сh_good = ""
...         ^
... '''
'        \xd1\x81h_good = ""\n        ^\n'
```

The `\xd1\x81` byte sequence there is UTF-8 for [U+0441 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES](http://codepoints.net/U+0441).

In other words, you used a cyrillic character, and in Python 2 that's an error.

Comment: Eugh. That is _not_ going to be useful for future visitors. Voting to close.

Comment: @JanDvorak: it is a rather obscure typo, indeed.